# Django dynamic multiple form

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, dynamic-forms

I have form for adding Company:

```
class Company(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=50, )
profile = models.ForeignKey("Profile", blank=True, null=True)
sector = models.ForeignKey("Sector", blank=True, null=True)
```

I want to dynamically add another form on same site when proper button is clicked. For example after clicking "Add Address" button, form should be extended with:

```
city = models.ForeignKey("City", blank=True, null=True)
street_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
```

and submiting this form will create new Customer, Address and CustomerAddress records. I already have worked out solution which isn't perfect, cause I added "blank=True", to fields in additional forms and show/hide form in JS. This soultion is causing another problem, because now I don't have any validation for form.

I don't want to create custom validation for every template, in which I add multiple forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a different form for each model, instead of using one form.

When the user clicks the "Add address" button, add a hidden input to the tempalte.

```
<input type="hidden" name="add-address" />
```

Then in your view, only instantiate the address form when the hidden input is present.

```
if "add-address" in request.POST:
    address_form = AddressForm(request.POST)
else:
    address_form = AddressForm()
```

This way, you can make the fields in your address form required.